# Typecasting a Mocked interface is resulting null when typecasted to actual class type

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, unity-container

I have a Class `TestManager` and its interface `ITestManager`

For above I have below mocking in a test case**

```
var lookupManager = new Mock<ITestManager>();
lookupManager.SetupGet(p => p.someMethod()).Returns("SomeDummyValue");

//registered this in the container with a mocked object
unitycontainer.RegisterInstance<ILookupAggregationManager>(lookupManager.Object);

//calling the method to be tested
targetObject.ExecuteTestCaseMethod();

//...
```

In actual code mocking is not working because of the below line, here **`as`** keyword is converting mocked type to actual class `TestManager`. This is resulting out null.

Is it possible to get the type from above mocking even after typecasting the proxy to actual type?

```
public void ExecuteTestCaseMethod()
{
    ITestManager lookupManager = this.container.Resolve<ITestManager>() as TestManager;    
}
```

Comment: No. Fix your code which tries to cast to a `TestManager`. If it's given an abstraction (`ITestManager`), it shouldn't be trying to cast that to a particular implementation

Comment: Also that subject member is tightly coupling to implementation details which would make isolating it in a unit test difficult.

Comment: got it. thank you  canton7 and  Nkosi. this is helpful

Comment: I pretty much agree it is bad design but in theory this could work if `TestManager` is not `sealed` and then you setup like `var mock = new Mock<TestManager>(); mock.As<ITestManager>().Setup(...)`

Comment: @Johnny Only if the methods being mocked are `virtual`

Comment: @canton7 I thought it doesn't matter since the mocked one will be `interface` method. Anyway, it is not the way to go.

Comment: @Johnny [Nope](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChHqBmAAgG9G2e3qrO3XsICSAMQgQ2AM0lsAvGzwwA7mwCyEMAGsJEABQBKANxDhPWRAB0AIQCGUI6YbCAvo3dMGFdgEs8GDBQ0nZgMGzichx8KGz2jiZsnj58AnpsIBF6jFwuvCkUsfFGCgB8fDQAnPoARHo1Jh7M7NQaWrpymdkMucIpymqFcQ4l8uUUVbWaOvWNDK5AA)